# Save querystring Bewteen Actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an index action that can be filtered and is done so by using a query string.  When I choose a record I move to the Details action.  From there I can navigate to other actions related to this record which will then lead me back to the Details action.  I would like to be able to save the URL from the Index page which will have the query string parameters intact.  Obviously I can't do this with a straight Request.UrlReferrer since it won't be correct if the previous action wasn't Index.  I have come up with a solution but I was wondering if there was a better way.  Thanks!

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    var url = Request.UrlReferrer;

    // Save URL if coming from the Employees/Index page
    if (url != null && url.AbsolutePath == "/Employees")
        Session.Add("OfficeURL", url.ToString());

    // Model Stuff

    return View();
}
```

Details View

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", null, new { @href = Session["OfficeURL"] })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a "return URL" with your links to the other views. Essentially:

**Index.cshtml**

```
@Html.ActionLink("View Details", "Details", "Foo", new { returnUrl = Request.RawUrl })
```

This will have the effect of putting the current index URL in the query string of the link. Then, in your other actions, you'll accept this as a param and store it in `ViewBag`:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ...

    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

Then, in these other views, you'll utilize this `ViewBag` member in the same way as above:

**Details.cshtml**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click Me!", "Foo", "Foo", new { returnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
```

When you're ready to go back to the index, then, you'd link/redirect to this return URL that you've been passing around.

Comment: Solution works well.  I assume this is the most common way to handle this request?